# How to get user defined views in a specific folder C# VSTO Outlook Add-in?

Tags: vsto, outlook-addin

After choosing any folder using folder picker, I want the user to be able to select outlook items from a specific user defined view. Is there any way to do it?

`NameSpace ns = null;
 Folder targetFolder = null;
 ns = Application.GetNamespace("MAPI");
 targetFolder = ns.PickFolder() as Folder;`

Code for picking folder.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [MAPIFolder.Views](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.outlook.mapifolder.views.aspx) collection.